# Can Microsoft Graph API copy a document to an on premises server?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API to copy documents to an Office 365 server. I am using this code, which works successfully

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'r+');
$stream = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream($handle);
$body = GuzzleHttp\Psr7\stream_for($stream->getContents());
$token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($token);
$request = $graph->createRequest("put", '/me/drive/root:/' . $orgFileName . ':/content');
$request->attachBody($body);
$response = $request->execute();
```

Is there a method available to copy a file to an on premises server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in the graph API. That is out of scope for it.

Uploading files to a local web server depends on how the local application expects the files. Graph API only knows about Office365.